# checking value in list - jinja2 template

Tags: flask, jinja2

I have written the below jinja2 template block,

```
{% if results["_id"] in session["notify_list"] %}
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-success my-1" data-toggle="modal" disabled>request already sent!!</button>
{% else %}
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success my-1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#{{results[i]['id']}}-req">
Request now</button>
% endif %}
```

and the session["collab_notify_list"] has ['5fb8044e481a2683c83653c6', '5fb947483c3c35442134df59', '5fb8044e481a2683c83653c6']

and the {{results["_id"]}} value is 5fb8044e481a2683c83653c6

though the value exists in the list, it is going to else statement, can someone help me what is the mistake in this?

Note: session["collab_notify_list"] is a list only

Comment: What is  results["_id"]? what is results[i]["_id"]? what is i actually? are you running a loop?

Comment: in your code you have: session["notify_list"] but are you saying that the key is "collab_notify_list"? Are you just checking the wrong key?